# Second order ODE near regular singular point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to self-study differential equations, and I have a doubt concerning the solution of the general second order differential equation:

$$P(x)y'' + Q(x)y' + R(x)y = 0$$

in the neighborhood of a regular singular point $x = 0$. According to the book I'm reading, the fact that $x = 0$ is a regular singular point means that $xQ(x)/P(x) = xp(x)$ and $x^2R(x)/P(x) = x^2q(x)$ have finite limits as $x\to 0$, and are analytic at $x=0$. Thus, they have convergent power series expansions of the form

$$xp(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_nx^n$$
$$x^2q(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q_nx^n$$

on some interval about the origin. According to this book, the coefficients $p_0$ and $q_0$ are given by the following limits:

$$p_0 = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{xQ(x)}{P(x)}$$

$$q_0 = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2R(x)}{P(x)}$$

My question is: why can $p_0$ and $q_0$ be calculated by the expressions above?

Answer (score 1):

The second order ODE has a regular singular point at $x=0$ iff there some disk centered at $0$ of radius $r > 0$ such that the differential equation has the form
$$
      y'' + \left(\frac{p_{0}}{x}+p_1+p_2x+pq_3x^{2}+\cdots\right)y'+\left(\frac{q_0}{x^{2}}+\frac{q_1}{x}+q_{2}+p_{3}x+\cdots\right)y=0,
$$
where the power series coefficients converge in the disk $D_{r}(0)$. There are various ways of saying the same thing, but that's what is going on. You can spot how to find $p_0$, $p_0$ from the limits you stated. The  **indicial** equation is the equation in $\rho$ obtained by substituting $y=x^{\rho}$ into the equation
$$
     y'' + \frac{p_0}{x}y'+\frac{q_0}{x^{2}}y=0, \\
       x^{2}y''+p_{0}xy'+q_{0}y=0.
$$
That is, the indicial equation is
$$
        \rho(\rho-1)+p_0\rho+q_0=0.
$$